# Observable subclass with public Notify<T>(T value) method

Tags: c#, system.reactive

Is there a subclass of the `Observable<T>` class that exposes access to `Notify<T>(T value)` method (or access `Notifier`, extension method) so that we can call `observable.Notify(t)` at hoc resulting all subscriptions being notified (`OnNext` invoked on the same thread).

I am not interested in `FromEventPattern`.

Comment: Are you looking for `Subject<T>` (and its friends)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `ISubject<T>` interface inherits both `IObservable<T>` and `IObserver<T>`.

```
var subject = new Subject<string>();
subject.Subscribe(text => Console.WriteLine(text));
subject.OnNext("Hello");
subject.OnNext("World!");
```

`IObserver<T>.OnNext` is essentially your `Notify` method.

More reading:

- [Using Subjects (MSDN)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Hh242970(v=VS.103).aspx)
- [`Subject<T>` (Introduction to Rx)](http://www.introtorx.com/Content/v1.0.10621.0/02_KeyTypes.html#Subject)

Answer (score 2):

You certainly can use `Subject<string>` to provide an object that is an observer (i.e. you can call `.OnNext(string)`) and is an observable that can be subscribed to.

The only downside is that any code with access to your `Subject<string>` can also call `.OnCompleted()` or `.OnError(...)` and break your subscribers' code.

The other alternative is to do this:

```
Action<string> notify = null;

var observable = Observable.FromEvent<string>(h => notify += h, h => notify -= h);

var subscription = observable.Subscribe(x => Console.WriteLine(x));

notify("Hello");
```

You now have a simple `Action<string>` delegate that you can call to push a value and just so long as you keep the subscription alive clients can't kill your program with rogue calls to `.OnCompleted()` or `.OnError(...)`.